# Creating record from another controller Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want a `Customization` record to be created from the `Campaign#create` method.

**Campaigns Controller**

```
  def create
    @campaign = Campaign.new(campaign_params)
    if @campaign.save
      @campaignitem = Customization.create(campaign_id: 1, product_id: 1)
    end
  end
```

**Campaign.rb**

```
has_many :customizations
```

**Customization.rb**

```
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :campaign
```

**I'm getting these 2 Activerecords errors when trying to save a Campaign**

```
["Product translation missing: es.activerecord.errors.models.customization.attributes.product.required",
 "Campaign translation missing: es.activerecord.errors.models.customization.attributes.campaign.required"]
```

**It's like if it won't get the campaign_id and product_id correctly**

Please help! I've been so many hours with this now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since rails 5 there is a presence validation for belongs_to relations. So there must be a product and campaign records with id = 1 in your situation. If you don't want this validation you can simply add optional option like this:

`belongs_to :product, optional: true`