# rspec controller create test with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a "Book" model and a "BookFormat" model (for "hardcover", "paperback" and so on).
The book model belongs_to book_format, and book_format has_many books. The book model hence has a book_format_id for the association. However this rspec test fails - the result is a 422 (unprocessable entity) instead of a 3xx (redirect). Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe BooksController, type: :controller do

  context 'Basic book routes' do
      ... (stuff omitted)
      describe 'CREATE /new' do
        it 'creates a book when the title and format is present' do
          post :create, params: { book: { title: 'A new book', book_format_id: '0' } }
          expect(response).to redirect_to(assigns(:book))
        end
      end
  end
end
```

The exact error from running rspec is:

```
1) BooksController Basic book routes GET /show CREATE /new creates a book when the title and format is present
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to(assigns(:book))
     
       Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <422: Unprocessable Entity>
       Response body: 
     # ./spec/requests/books_spec.rb:30:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**Amended test** - trying to ensure that the book_format ID really exists:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe BooksController, type: :controller do

  before(:all) do
    @hardcover = create(:hardcover)
  end

  context 'Basic book routes' do
      describe 'CREATE /new' do
        it 'creates a book when the title and format is present' do
          post :create, params: { book: { title: 'A new book', book_format_id: @hardcover.id } }
          debugger
          expect(response).to redirect_to(assigns(:book))
        end
```

And I have a factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :hardcover, class: BookFormat do
    format { 'Hardcover' }
  end
end
```

Comment: i think i know the reason but for to be sure can you share the book objects error messages.

Comment: added above - but I only can post the error from rspec. I have a very similar test that tests whether a book is valid, and it works (model test, essentially book = Book.new(title: 'The Hobbit', book_format_id: 1), and then expect(book.valid?).to eq(true))

Comment: i think your problem is presence validation of belongs_to  relation. Here  my answer for the same problem hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/73197428/5194116

Comment: thanks - yes I understand that. However I DO want this relation to be mandatory. As you can see - I am passing a book_format_id along with the params, so this should work out but it doesn't seem to...

Comment: then you should pass a book_format_id that belongs a persisted book_format record

Comment: I get that... and that is what is puzzling me. As said, I can create a book by passing book_format_id: 1 into Book.new - see my comment with the model test above... but in the request test, the same thing does not work. I have amended my test to explicitely create a book_format and to use THAT ID- still the same problem. Amended version pasted above.

Comment: i need to see the error messages that came from active record. can you share the result of this code `JSON.parse(response.body)` where you get 422 response.

Comment: ok so that is weird. response.body equals to "" - and hence, JSON.parse(response.body) gives an error (eval error: 859: unexpected token at '')

Comment: then you should put debugger on the controller and check if the book_format_id coming properly, book_format exists with that id. also checking the errors of the book object to see the exact error on that request will help you to understand what is going wrong

Comment: the problem was simple: I recently added the book_format model and forgot to add book_format_id to book_params :) thanks for your help.